# Modal viewController presented from UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a class that is a subclass of UITabBarController which contains 4 child viewControllers. I've added a button similar to RedLaser, Instagram, Path, DailyBooth, and other apps. Mine is like the top example here:

[image: Image of tabBar with center button]

This button calls a method in the TabBarController which presents a modal viewController. When it's dismissed, the NavigationControllers in the currently selected viewController starts to behave strangely. The pop animation is all messed up and other small bugs happen until you select another tab on the tabBar. Then the animations are fine until the viewController is presented again.

I'm sure it's because I'm dismissing it incorrectly, but I'm not sure how this is to be done.

this is my code in the TabBarController:

```
-(void)showScanner {
    ZBarReaderViewController *reader = [[ZBarReaderViewController alloc] init];
    reader.readerDelegate = self;
    reader.supportedOrientationsMask = ZBarOrientationMaskAll;

    ZBarImageScanner *scanner = reader.scanner;
    [scanner setSymbology:ZBAR_I25
                   config:ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
                       to:0];
    [scanner setSymbology:ZBAR_QRCODE
                   config:ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
                       to:0];

    [reader setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
    [self presentModalViewController:reader
                            animated:YES];
    [reader release];
    //[self playBeep];
    }

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker     didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    id<NSFastEnumeration> results = [info objectForKey:ZBarReaderControllerResults];
    ZBarSymbol *symbol = nil;
    for (symbol in results)
        break;
    NSString *barcode = symbol.data;

    UINavigationController *searchNavController = [[self viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1];
    WLSearchViewController *searchVC = [searchNavController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];

    //    WLSearchViewController *searchVC = [[self viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1];
    //[searchNavController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [self setSelectedViewController:searchNavController];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    [self playBeep];

    [searchVC handleSearchForTerm:barcode];
}

-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found what was wrong, figured I'd post this to help anyone else who's facing this.

I had overridden a viewDidAppear:animated: in my tabBarController but I didn't call `[super viewDidAppear:animated:]`

Added that and everything was better!